# Giving coordinates in a projective plane

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

When we are giving coordinates to the points of the Fano plane, we do so by giving every point a triplet: $(a_1, a_2,a_3)$ from $\mathbb F_2$ so that if three points are collinear then the pointwise sum of their coordinates $mod \space 2$ is $0$.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fano_plane#Homogeneous_coordinates

It is the case when we have $2^2+2^1+1=7$ points. But how do we generalise collinearity for projective planes with $n^2+n+1$ points and coordinates from $\mathbb F_n$? (e.g. when are three points collinear when we have $n=4$ so $21$ points and $a_1,a_2,a_3 $ are from $\mathbb F_4$?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the general case, remember that each point in the projective plane is represented by $n-1$ different vectors in $\mathbb F_n^3$ (which are all scalar multiples of each other).

$3$ *different* projective points are collinear exactly if a set containing a representative of each of them span a *two-dimensional* subspace of $\mathbb F_n^3$.

Another way to express this condition is that if $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ and $(b_1,b_2,b_3)$ and $(c_1,c_2,c_3)$ represent three (not necessarily different) projective points, then they are collinear iff the matrix
$$ \begin{bmatrix}a_1 & b_1 & c_1 \\ a_2 & b_2 & c_2 \\  a_3 & b_3 & c_3 \end{bmatrix} $$ is *singular* -- that is, if its determinant is $0$, or in yet other words if $((a_1,a_2,a_3)\times(b_1,b_2,b_3))\cdot(c_1,c_2,c_3)=0$.

---

Note that this doesn't reduce to the nice simple rule for the Fano plane when $n=2$. The existence of the simple rule depends critically on the fact that every line contains exactly three points, so when you have two different points, you can *compute* directly what the third one must be: $\vec c = \vec a + \vec b$ is the only element in $\operatorname{span}(\vec a,\vec b)$ that isn't either zero or one of the known points. Since we're in characteristic $2$, this is the same as $\vec a + \vec b + \vec c = 0$.